# Tension in string - Downward force vs hanging a mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A light cord is wrapped around a wheel (a disk). It is pulled downwards in 2 ways. Case 1- By a steady downward force F. Case 2 - By attaching a weight equivalent to F. In the 2nd case, tension will be less. I am struggling to understand how tension will be different by the same magnitude of force.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case the force is only accelerating the wheel.

In the second case the same magnitude force is accelerating a mass and the wheel.
The applied force needs to be "split" to accelerate both the mass and the wheel.
The agent that does the "splitting" is the string by pulling up on the mass and pulling down on the wheel.
The tension in the string adjusts itself so that the downward linear acceleration of the mass is exactly equal to the tangential linear acceleration of the rim of the wheel.
This means that the tension in the string must be greater than zero but less than the weight of the mass.

Comment: neat. thx so much :)